# Nvidia driver failure after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, update-manager, gpu

After upgrading my os to Ubuntu 22.04.4 my system was working fine until I **tried updating software (through software updates) and my graphics card driver.** Now the **driver keeps failing** and reverting back to X.Org x server, even after reverting to the previous one.

At boot console returns this:

```
idevisdcz: clean, 870460/8003584 files, 27005868/32000000 blocks
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS seryice responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD.itoFS Service responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD.vice responder private socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAN Service responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket
```

Not sure it's related, but while trying to install amd pro drivers the installer script returned this error:

```
E: Package 'linux-headers-5.13.0-37-generic' has no installation candidate
```

and when I run `ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)` I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Did I mess up?

My system:

```
  Kernel: 5.13.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0
  Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 tk: GTK 3.24.33 vt: 2 dm: GDM3 42.0
  Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
  Device-1: NVIDIA GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] vendor: Micro-Star MSI
```

Comment: Where did you get that kernel? 22.04 released with the 5.15 kernel and is currently on 6.5 for hwe

Comment: Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 using Canonical's instructions.
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start

Comment: That message saying it has no installation candidate says you did something funky.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently I didn't update grub after my upgrade.

After running `sudo update-grub` system booted with the new kernel.